# How to set the specific value for checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make if they select r6 until y20 the value still fix 4.2 at textbox28 but if they tick 
r6 = 0.222,

y10 = 0.4

y12 = 0.5

y20 = .7

(Val(r6.Value) + Val(TextBox33.Value) + Val(TextBox36.Value) + Val(TextBox26.Value)) - this indicates the formula x * y * the value that they tick at the checkbox

```
If r6 Then TextBox28.Value = 4.2
If Y10 Then TextBox28.Value = 4.2
If Y12 Then TextBox28.Value = 4.2
If Y20 Then TextBox28.Value = 4.2

'calculation for amount' 
ttlqty.Value = Val(length.Value) * Val(nos.Value) * (the one that they tick)

'calculation for totalqty'
TextBox29.Value = Val(TextBox28.Value) * Val(TextBox27.Value)
```

And if the user select r6. The calculation will be

 2 * 3 * 0.222

if they untick r6 and tick y10. The calculation will be

 2 * 3 * 0.4

Comment: Are you asking how to format the number? Your question is cut off / incomplete so it's difficult to understand what you want.

Comment: wait. i just realised its cut off. and if the user select r6 the (the one that they tick) this one will be 0.2222. i dont know how to do it.